# Prove $ \frac{1}{C_{\alpha}}(x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha}) \le (x + y)^{\alpha} \le C_{\alpha}(x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha}) $

Tags: calculus

> Suppose that $ 0 < \alpha < 1 $. Show that there is a constant $ C_{\alpha} $ so that for $ x, y \in (0, +\infty) $ we have the estimate
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{1}{C_{\alpha}}(x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha}) \le (x + y)^{\alpha} \le C_{\alpha}(x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha})
> \end{equation}

---

I tried to divide the expression by $ x^{\alpha} $ and to use Taylor's series, but it didn't work out. Can anybody hint what this problem is about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing by $x^\alpha$ is a good idea: we are now reduced to show that there is $C=C_\alpha$ such that for all $t\in (0,\infty)$,
$$\frac 1C(1+t^\alpha)\leqslant (1+t)^\alpha\leqslant C(1+t^\alpha).$$
This can be done noticing that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1+t^\alpha}{(1+t)^\alpha}=1=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1+t^\alpha}{(1+t)^\alpha}$.

A more careful analysis can give an explicit expression for $C_\alpha$.

Comment: Then exists $ t_0 : \forall t > t_0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2} < \frac{(1 + t)^{\alpha}}{1 + t^{\alpha}} < 2 $. Denote $ C_0 = \max{\frac{1 + t^{\alpha}}{(1 + t)^{\alpha}}} \text{for } t \in [0, t_0] $, then we can choose $ C_{\alpha} = \max\{C_0, 2\} $, right?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$